# Jenkins - Backup Configuration of Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to backup configuration of job, I am using to do this ThinBackup plugin in version 1.7.4 . And in every configuration of the job, there is something like `Promote builds when..`, how to backup this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue and found this is an [open bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21472). Looks to have a fix but a new version of the plugin hasn't been released.

A workaround which seems to work OK so far, is to separately backup the `config.xml` files under the `JENKINS_HOME/jobs/`.  On Linux I ran the below from the Jenkins home directory to create this additional backup:

```
 $ find jobs -name config.xml -exec tar -rzvf /tmp/config.xml-BACKUP.tgz {} \;
```

So I'm still using ThinBackup to get all the other bits but after restoring its backup:

```
tar -xzf /tmp/config.xml-BACKUP.tgz
```

I then restored the jobs `config.xml` backup and restarted Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

They are a some options with the ThinBackup plugin:

[image]

Did you try to enable the "Backup build archive" option?

Comment: Which version of Jenkins do you use?